# My cloud formation template fails to create resource without producing any error

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sns, aws-cloudformation

I have a large template for CloudFormation that has hundreds of resources. All are successfully updated, during an update, except one: an SNS alarm topic.

When deploying the stack, I get no errors, but even if the topic is non-existent the topic is never created.

I'm not expecting anyone to be able to provide me with a solution, but I would simply like to know how to troubleshoot the problem. It would be helpful to get output from the deployment, but the events are so few and really don't reflect the amount of resources being updated/created that they rarely help finding out what goes wrong.

Validation of the template is also successful, but that's almost a given since deploying also succeeds.

Comment: I have, of course, continued to mull over the problem and I've read that you can't update a topic, does this in fact mean that you can't create a topic during a cloud formation update?

Comment: my tests show that although you can't update an existing topic (fails with the reason `Update to resource type AWS::SNS::Topic is not supported.`), you _can_ create a new topic during a CloudFormation update of an existing stack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding troubleshooting live CloudFormation stacks in general, CloudFormation just recently added support for [Change Sets](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-change-sets-for-aws-cloudformation/), which should help you preview changes and troubleshoot potential issues with updates before you attempt to apply them to your running stack.

Regarding SNS topics specifically, creating an SNS topic from scratch using the [AWS::SNS::Topic](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-sns-topic.html) resource works correctly. However, if you are using a [`TopicName`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-sns-topic.html#cfn-sns-topic-name) property in your SNS resource, make sure that the name is unique across your entire AWS Account, as noted in the [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-name.html):

> Resource names must be unique across all of your active stacks. If you reuse templates to create multiple stacks, you must change or remove custom names from your template.

So reusing a constant `TopicName` in a stack deployed multiple times could cause the issue you're describing.

Also, if you're attempting to update existing CloudFormation-created topics with added/removed subscriptions, note the following **important** notice in the [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-sns-topic.html):

> **Important**
>
> After you create an Amazon SNS topic, you cannot update its properties by using AWS CloudFormation. You can modify an Amazon SNS topic by using the AWS Management Console.

As a potential workaround for adding/removing subscriptions to existing SNS topics via CloudFormation, there is a [cloudformation-helpers](https://github.com/gilt/cloudformation-helpers) library containing a [`Custom::SnsSubscription`](https://github.com/gilt/cloudformation-helpers#subscribe-to-sns-topics) resource ([example](https://github.com/gilt/cloudformation-helpers/blob/master/test/aws/sns.subscribe.template)) that might help.

Comment: Before you provided this answer (good job though, it is well written and will hopefully help others) I found that the last part is what was my problem.